# Is it possible to make rainbow gradient ::selection

Tags: css, gradient, selection, linear-gradients

I am trying to make a rainbow gradient `::selection`, I have tried this:

```css
::selection {
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 154, 0, 1) 10%,
    rgba(208, 222, 33, 1) 20%,
    rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 30%,
    rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 40%,
    rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%,
    rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 60%,
    rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 70%,
    rgba(186, 12, 248, 1) 80%,
    rgba(251, 7, 217, 1) 90%,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%
  );
  color: white;
}
```

but it just appears as if I did this:

```css
::selection {
  background: white;
  color: white;
}
```

Is it possible to have a rainbow gradient? Preferably with no JavaScript? I have looked all over, but none of them look good, and all of them use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done using a gradient on `::selection`, because background-image isn't supported. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection):

> Only certain CSS properties can be used with ::selection:
>
> - color
> - background-color
> - text-decoration and its associated properties
> - text-shadow
> - stroke-color, fill-color and stroke-width
> - ***In particular, background-image is ignored.***

Comment: So basically no?

Comment: Correct. Can't be done in using a gradient on `::selected`.